# Is it possible to call a derived class's method from a base class? E.G; Avoid 'slicing'

Tags: c++

Let's say that there's some classes, all deriving from a base class named Animal:

```
Cat
Dog
Parrot
EveryAnimalInExistance
```

Each class implements their own method of abstract methods such as:

```
attack()
defend()
hunt()
breed()
```

Then there's a method called

```
observeAnimal(Animal* everyAnimalInExistance)
```

How do I pass any potential animal from a potential range of thousands of them, and simply call

```
everyAnimalInExistance.hunt();
```

As I understand, in c++ the object would be 'sliced' and it would attempt to call the base class's own methods and that typecasting is required to call the correct method.

I cannot be certain if RTTI is available in every environment of the project as it's vast and numerous, can anyone enlighten me on the approach I should take?

Comment: There is no object to slice, because you have a base class pointer. The problem is that the base class doesn't have the method you want to call. You would have to try to `dynamic_cast` to a pointer to the right derived type. This probably a sign that the design is broken.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, do virtual methods have a mandatory requirement of needing to be implemented? EG; not all Animals hunt()

Comment: @BoBTFish

Yes, I think it should be a problem in my code, thanks for the quick response!

Comment: Only *pure* virtual methods must be implemented (i.e. `virtual void hunt() = 0;`) so a regular virtual method wouldn't have to be. *But*, but if you have an `Animal` which has a virtual `hunt` function and then derive a `Rabbit` you can still call `r->hunt()` if `r` is of type `Rabbit*` and you'll get `Animal::hunt`.

Comment: Unless it is a Monty Python [Killer Rabbit](http://worstprofessorever.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/02/rabbit.jpg) and you have to implement both `hunt()` and `attack()`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `observeAnimal(Animal* everyAnimalInExistance)` method performs no slicing, as the parameter is received through a pointer.

In case of pointers or references, virtual functions will be called correctly in your zoo :) . Slicing only happens when you pass `everyAnimalInExistance` by value.

In other words:

```
class Animal {
    virtual void hunt() = 0;
}

observeAnimal(Animal* everyAnimalInExistance)
{
    everyAnimalInExistance->hunt(); // correct
}
observeAnimal(Animal everyAnimalInExistance)
{
    everyAnimalInExistance.hunt(); // sliced, incorrect (call into base class)
}
observeAnimal(Animal& everyAnimalInExistance)
{
    everyAnimalInExistance.hunt(); // correct
}

std::vector<Animal> slice_and_dice;
// add animals to vector here (actually this vector will slice the animals
// when you add them)
slice_and_dice[0].hunt(); // incorrect, sliced

std::vector<Animal*> pointer_zoo;
// add animals to vector here
pointer_zoo[0]->hunt(); // correct
```

Answer (score 0):

Answering you head question directly ... yes, there is (at least ) a way to call a derived class method from the base class, the [Curiously Recurring Template Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern). In fact that is called Static polymorphism